# ros2 how to make turtlesim use the same turtle every time?

Tags: ros2, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when launching turtlesim I usually get a different looking turtle bot every time, probably it's random.
Is there some variable I can use to make turtlesim use the same specific turtle every time ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400084/ros2-how-to-make-turtlesim-use-the-same-turtle-every-time-?/) by [flanel](https://answers.ros.org/users/103987/flanel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only parameters that show up in rqt's Dynamic Reconfigure (at least in Foxy) are `background_b` `background_g` `background_r` and `use_sim_time` so I don't think so.

EDIT: So I checked the source code and I found out that it is indeed random. However, [this portion](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/1fd5ea7c166837ce01a0fb4d00133987ed08d78d/turtlesim/src/turtle_frame.cpp#L88-L94) is interesting. That code basically adds all the images from `turtlesim/images` to a vector and that vector is used to [randomly](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/1fd5ea7c166837ce01a0fb4d00133987ed08d78d/turtlesim/src/turtle_frame.cpp#L177-L180) pick a turtlebot.

This means you *could* build [ros tutorials](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/foxy-devel) from source and simply delete all the files from the folder `turtlesim/images` except the one you want.

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I am 95% sure this is the only way to use the same turtlesim every time.

EDIT 2. I decided to check if it would work. There is 1 small thing you need to change to the source code (besides removing the other images from the folder) to get it to work.

[This portion](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/1fd5ea7c166837ce01a0fb4d00133987ed08d78d/turtlesim/src/turtle_frame.cpp#L80-L86) is used to create the vector of images. More specifically *its length* is used. If you don't change it, there will be a vector of 6 'images' where only the first one really exists and the other 'images' don't exist.

So in order to get it to work, you need to remove the appends except for the append of the turtle you want (e.g. if you want to use the 'ardent' one, remove line 82-86).

I'm not sure if you find it worth it to go through all of this just to get the same turtle, but that's the way I found to do it.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flanel](https://answers.ros.org/users/103987/flanel/) on 2022-05-05**:
:) Really really appreciate the effort on this tiny question. Your details gave me another idea. I'll just try to rename/replace all the other images with the one I want and see if it works.

Thank you very much

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-05**:
That might work too. However, it might also depend on those images having those names, so you might still need to rename them `ardent.png` `bouncy.png` etc. even if they're all copies of the foxy one (for instance). EDIT you already mentioned rename, so nevermind.

**Comment by [flanel](https://answers.ros.org/users/103987/flanel/) on 2022-05-06**:
Confirmed, it works with replace/rename, thanks @Joe28965